# Сериализация и десериализация содержимого datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid, сериализация

нужно сделать серилизацию данных из datagrid. И вывод инфы из файла в datagrid.
Вот что получилось, но сериализация не работает. Подскажите, как исправить, пожалуйста.

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Zapic>));

public istochnik()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel();
    }

[Serializable]
    public class Zapic: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string one {get;set;}
        public string two { get; set; }
        public string three { get; set; }
        public string four { get; set; }
        public string five { get; set; }

        public string One
        {
            get { return one; }
            set
            {
                one = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("One");
            }
        }

        public string Two
        {
            get { return two; }
            set
            {
                two = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Two");
            }
        }

        public string Three
        {
            get { return three; }
            set
            {
                three = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Three");
            }
        }

        public string Four
        {
            get { return four; }
            set
            {
                four = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Four");
            }
        }

        public string Five
        {
            get { return five; }
            set
            {
                five = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Five");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Zapic selectedZapic;

        public ObservableCollection<Zapic> Zapics { get; set; }
        public Zapic SelectedZapic
        {
            get { return selectedZapic; }
            set
            {
                selectedZapic = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedZapic");
            }
        }

        public ApplicationViewModel()
        {
             Zapics = new ObservableCollection<Zapic>
        {
             new Zapic {One="Введите название" },
        };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

private void Serial_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("xml.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, Zapics);
        }
    }

private void Desir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("xml.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            ObservableCollection<Zapic> newZapic = (ObservableCollection<Zapic>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="tablezapic" ItemsSource="{Binding Zapics}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedZapic}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" Margin="10,10,11,4.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=One}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Two}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Three}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Four}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Что значит `не работает`?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что именно идет не так при выполнении Вашего приложения? Также, позвольте сделать Вам несколько замечаний по коду: Не стоит называть идентификаторы в коде транслитом, Zapic => Record, Istochnik => Source. Имена классов и методов всегда начинаются с заглавной буквы, а слова в названиях не стоит сокращать: Serial_Click => SerializeClick, Desir_Click => Deserialize_Click.